# Building MFC Automation example (to access Excel using OLE automation). Can't compile

Tags: windows, excel, ole-automation

I'm trying to build the example described at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/178749/EN-US/  in order to build an application that programatically accesses Excel using Automation.  I have Visual C++ 2005/Visual Studio 2005.  Some of the instructions don't exactly match up (classwizard, mostly), but the general idea seems to be the same.

Problems: I don't end up with an excel.h file after using the "new class" to create my wrapper classes.  So I can' t #include that file as it specifies in step 13.  I do get a excel.tlh and an excel.tli in my windebug directory, but that doesn't seem to work.  I tried all orders for

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "debug/excel.tli"
#include "debug/excel.tlh"
```

... including leaving one of those files out of the compile, but I still end up with a ton of compile errors.

Here's the top 5 compile errors with the above #includes:

```
1>c:\users\sniles\documents\visual studio 2005\source10\testole\testole\debug\excel.tli(14) : error C2653: 'Adjustments' : is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\users\sniles\documents\visual studio 2005\source10\testole\testole\debug\excel.tli(14) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'GetParent'
1>c:\users\sniles\documents\visual studio 2005\source10\testole\testole\debug\excel.tli(14) : error C2433: 'IDispatchPtr' : 'inline' not permitted on data declarations
1>c:\users\sniles\documents\visual studio 2005\source10\testole\testole\debug\excel.tli(14) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\sniles\documents\visual studio 2005\source10\testole\testole\debug\excel.tli(14) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\sniles\documents\visual studio 2005\source10\testole\testole\debug\excel.tli(16) : error C3861: 'get_Parent': identifier not found
```

Here's the top 5 errors with these includes:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "debug/excel.tlh"

1>c:\users\sniles\documents\visual studio 2005\source10\testole\testole\debug\excel.tlh(550) : error C3121: cannot change GUID for class 'IFilter'
1>        c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0\include\comdef.h(483) : see declaration of 'IFilter'
1>c:\users\sniles\documents\visual studio 2005\source10\testole\testole\debug\excel.tlh(1541) : error C2786: 'BOOL (__stdcall *)(HDC,int,int,int,int)' : invalid operand for __uuidof
1>c:\users\sniles\documents\visual studio 2005\source10\testole\testole\debug\excel.tlh(1541) : error C2923: '_com_IIID' : 'Rectangle' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Interface'
1>        c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0\include\wingdi.h(3667) : see declaration of 'Rectangle'
1>c:\users\sniles\documents\visual studio 2005\source10\testole\testole\debug\excel.tlh(1541) : error C3203: '_com_IIID' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter '_IIID', expected a real type
```

Here's the top 5 errors with these includes:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "debug/excel.tli"

1>c:\users\sniles\documents\visual studio 2005\source10\testole\testole\debug\excel.tli(14) : error C2653: 'Adjustments' : is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\users\sniles\documents\visual studio 2005\source10\testole\testole\debug\excel.tli(14) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'GetParent'
1>c:\users\sniles\documents\visual studio 2005\source10\testole\testole\debug\excel.tli(14) : error C2433: 'IDispatchPtr' : 'inline' not permitted on data declarations
1>c:\users\sniles\documents\visual studio 2005\source10\testole\testole\debug\excel.tli(14) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\sniles\documents\visual studio 2005\source10\testole\testole\debug\excel.tli(14) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the ClassWizard wrapper generator, but it looks like it may have #imported the Excel COM type library without a namespace, and you're getting conflicts with the SDK header files. Check the `.tlh` file and ensure there's a namespace around the definitions. If not, I'd look at importing it the more manual (but safer) way using #import.

Check out using #import directly; it will generate the `.tlh` and `.tli` files in the build directory, which you can then use directory with `CComPtr<>` and the like. I've found that to be much more straightforward than using CW wrapper classes. That's my advice anyway.

Comment: Did what you suggested. Now getting same problem as this: http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-263709.html

Comment: Check the generated .tlh file in the build directory, and see what it's #importing. Chances are it's importing an Office library which is not in your compilation include path which is causing the error.

Comment: No imports in the tlh files. Only #include is for <comdef.h>, which does resolve.

Comment: Can you post the top of the .tlh file (up to the error line at least) and the specific build error output? I don't have that version of office so I can't replicate it, and it's not something I have done specifically, but if you post those two items someone might be able to say what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps but generally you `#import` the type library but you do NOT `#include` the .tli and .tlh files (the `#import` implicitly does this).

Also, remember there are two ways of calling a COM server in MFC.

1. Use `#import` which basically creates smart ATL pointers to create COM objects and call methods.
2. Use the class wizard to create an `IDispatch` style class wrapper to create COM object and call the methods.

Answer (score 0):

At Nick's request, I'm posting the build error output and following that the `vbe6ext.tlh`  file, up to the error:

```
********************* Build output:

1>------ Build started: Project: testole, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>testoleDlg.cpp
1>c:\users\sniles\documents\visual studio 2005\source10\testole\testole\debug\vbe6ext.tlh(463) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier '__missing_type__'
1>c:\users\sniles\documents\visual studio 2005\source10\testole\testole\testoledlg.cpp(164) : error C2065: '_Application' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\sniles\documents\visual studio 2005\source10\testole\testole\testoledlg.cpp(164) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'app'
1>c:\users\sniles\documents\visual studio 2005\source10\testole\testole\testoledlg.cpp(164) : error C2065: 'app' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\sniles\documents\visual studio 2005\source10\testole\testole\testoledlg.cpp(166) : error C2228: left of '.CreateDispatch' must have class/struct/union
1>        type is ''unknown-type''
1>c:\users\sniles\documents\visual studio 2005\source10\testole\testole\testoledlg.cpp(172) : error C2228: left of '.SetVisible' must have class/struct/union
1>        type is ''unknown-type''
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\sniles\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Source10\testole\testole\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>testole - 6 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

*******************  vbe6ext.tlh
// Created by Microsoft (R) C/C++ Compiler Version 14.00.50727.42 (e112bc16).
//
// c:\users\sniles\documents\visual studio 2005\source10\testole\testole\debug\vbe6ext.tlh
//
// C++ source equivalent of Win32 type library C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA6\VBE6EXT.OLB
// compiler-generated file created 10/10/08 at 14:03:16 - DO NOT EDIT!

#pragma once
#pragma pack(push, 8)

#include <comdef.h>

namespace VBIDE {

//
// Forward references and typedefs
//

struct __declspec(uuid("0002e157-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
/* LIBID */ __VBIDE;
struct __declspec(uuid("0002e158-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
/* dual interface */ Application;
enum vbextFileTypes;
struct __declspec(uuid("0002e166-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
/* dual interface */ testVBE;
enum vbext_WindowType;
enum vbext_WindowState;
struct __declspec(uuid("0002e16b-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
/* dual interface */ Window;
struct __declspec(uuid("0002e16a-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
/* dual interface */ _Windows_old;
struct __declspec(uuid("f57b7ed0-d8ab-11d1-85df-00c04f98f42c"))
/* dual interface */ _Windows;
struct /* coclass */ Windows;
struct __declspec(uuid("0002e16c-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
/* dual interface */ _LinkedWindows;
struct /* coclass */ LinkedWindows;
struct __declspec(uuid("0002e167-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
/* dual interface */ Events;
struct __declspec(uuid("0002e113-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
/* interface */ _VBProjectsEvents;
struct __declspec(uuid("0002e103-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
/* dispinterface */ _dispVBProjectsEvents;
struct __declspec(uuid("0002e115-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
/* interface */ _VBComponentsEvents;
struct __declspec(uuid("0002e116-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
/* dispinterface */ _dispVBComponentsEvents;
struct __declspec(uuid("0002e11a-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
/* interface */ _ReferencesEvents;
struct __declspec(uuid("0002e118-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
/* dispinterface */ _dispReferencesEvents;
struct /* coclass */ ReferencesEvents;
struct __declspec(uuid("0002e130-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
/* interface */ _CommandBarControlEvents;
struct __declspec(uuid("0002e131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
/* dispinterface */ _dispCommandBarControlEvents;
struct /* coclass */ CommandBarEvents;
struct __declspec(uuid("0002e159-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
/* dual interface */ _ProjectTemplate;
struct /* coclass */ ProjectTemplate;
enum vbext_ProjectType;
enum vbext_ProjectProtection;
enum vbext_VBAMode;
struct __declspec(uuid("0002e160-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
/* dual interface */ _VBProject_Old;
struct __declspec(uuid("eee00915-e393-11d1-bb03-00c04fb6c4a6"))
/* dual interface */ _VBProject;
struct /* coclass */ VBProject;
struct __declspec(uuid("0002e165-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
/* dual interface */ _VBProjects_Old;
struct __declspec(uuid("eee00919-e393-11d1-bb03-00c04fb6c4a6"))
/* dual interface */ _VBProjects;
struct /* coclass */ VBProjects;
struct __declspec(uuid("be39f3d4-1b13-11d0-887f-00a0c90f2744"))
/* dual interface */ SelectedComponents;
enum vbext_ComponentType;
struct __declspec(uuid("0002e161-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
/* dual interface */ _Components;
struct /* coclass */ Components;
struct __declspec(uuid("0002e162-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
/* dual interface */ _VBComponents_Old;
struct __declspec(uuid("eee0091c-e393-11d1-bb03-00c04fb6c4a6"))
/* dual interface */ _VBComponents;
struct /* coclass */ VBComponents;
struct __declspec(uuid("0002e163-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
/* dual interface */ _Component;
struct /* coclass */ Component;
struct __declspec(uuid("0002e164-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
/* dual interface */ _VBComponent_Old;
struct __declspec(uuid("eee00921-e393-11d1-bb03-00c04fb6c4a6"))
/* dual interface */ _VBComponent;
struct /* coclass */ VBComponent;
struct __declspec(uuid("0002e18c-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
/* dual interface */ Property;
struct __declspec(uuid("0002e188-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
/* dual interface */ _Properties;
struct /* coclass */ Properties;
struct __declspec(uuid("da936b62-ac8b-11d1-b6e5-00a0c90f2744"))
/* dual interface */ _AddIns;
struct /* coclass */ Addins;
struct __declspec(uuid("da936b64-ac8b-11d1-b6e5-00a0c90f2744"))
/* dual interface */ AddIn;
enum vbext_ProcKind;
struct __declspec(uuid("0002e16e-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
/* dual interface */ _CodeModule;
struct /* coclass */ CodeModule;
struct __declspec(uuid("0002e172-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
/* dual interface */ _CodePanes;
struct /* coclass */ CodePanes;
enum vbext_CodePaneview;
struct __declspec(uuid("0002e176-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
/* dual interface */ _CodePane;
struct /* coclass */ CodePane;
struct __declspec(uuid("0002e17a-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
/* dual interface */ _References;
enum vbext_RefKind;
struct __declspec(uuid("0002e17e-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
/* dual interface */ ignorethis;
struct __declspec(uuid("cdde3804-2064-11cf-867f-00aa005ff34a"))
/* dispinterface */ _dispReferences_Events;
struct /* coclass */ References;

//
// Smart pointer typedef declarations
//

_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(Application, __uuidof(Application));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(_VBProjectsEvents, __uuidof(_VBProjectsEvents));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(_dispVBProjectsEvents, __uuidof(_dispVBProjectsEvents));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(_VBComponentsEvents, __uuidof(_VBComponentsEvents));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(_dispVBComponentsEvents, __uuidof(_dispVBComponentsEvents));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(_ReferencesEvents, __uuidof(_ReferencesEvents));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(_dispReferencesEvents, __uuidof(_dispReferencesEvents));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(_CommandBarControlEvents, __uuidof(_CommandBarControlEvents));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(_dispCommandBarControlEvents, __uuidof(_dispCommandBarControlEvents));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(_ProjectTemplate, __uuidof(_ProjectTemplate));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(Events, __uuidof(Events));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(_Component, __uuidof(_Component));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(SelectedComponents, __uuidof(SelectedComponents));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(_dispReferences_Events, __uuidof(_dispReferences_Events));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(testVBE, __uuidof(testVBE));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(Window, __uuidof(Window));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(_Windows_old, __uuidof(_Windows_old));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(_LinkedWindows, __uuidof(_LinkedWindows));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(_VBProject_Old, __uuidof(_VBProject_Old));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(_VBProject, __uuidof(_VBProject));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(_VBProjects_Old, __uuidof(_VBProjects_Old));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(_VBProjects, __uuidof(_VBProjects));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(_Components, __uuidof(_Components));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(_VBComponents_Old, __uuidof(_VBComponents_Old));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(_VBComponents, __uuidof(_VBComponents));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(_VBComponent_Old, __uuidof(_VBComponent_Old));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(_VBComponent, __uuidof(_VBComponent));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(Property, __uuidof(Property));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(_Properties, __uuidof(_Properties));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(AddIn, __uuidof(AddIn));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(_Windows, __uuidof(_Windows));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(_AddIns, __uuidof(_AddIns));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(_CodeModule, __uuidof(_CodeModule));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(_CodePanes, __uuidof(_CodePanes));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(_CodePane, __uuidof(_CodePane));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(ignorethis, __uuidof(ignorethis));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(_References, __uuidof(_References));

//
// Type library items
//

struct __declspec(uuid("0002e158-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
Application : IDispatch
{
    //
    // Raw methods provided by interface
    //

      virtual HRESULT __stdcall get_Version (
        /*[out,retval]*/ BSTR * lpbstrReturn ) = 0;
};

enum __declspec(uuid("06a03650-2369-11ce-bfdc-08002b2b8cda"))
vbextFileTypes
{
    vbextFileTypeForm = 0,
    vbextFileTypeModule = 1,
    vbextFileTypeClass = 2,
    vbextFileTypeProject = 3,
    vbextFileTypeExe = 4,
    vbextFileTypeFrx = 5,
    vbextFileTypeRes = 6,
    vbextFileTypeUserControl = 7,
    vbextFileTypePropertyPage = 8,
    vbextFileTypeDocObject = 9,
    vbextFileTypeBinary = 10,
    vbextFileTypeGroupProject = 11,
    vbextFileTypeDesigners = 12
};

enum __declspec(uuid("be39f3db-1b13-11d0-887f-00a0c90f2744"))
vbext_WindowType
{
    vbext_wt_CodeWindow = 0,
    vbext_wt_Designer = 1,
    vbext_wt_Browser = 2,
    vbext_wt_Watch = 3,
    vbext_wt_Locals = 4,
    vbext_wt_Immediate = 5,
    vbext_wt_ProjectWindow = 6,
    vbext_wt_PropertyWindow = 7,
    vbext_wt_Find = 8,
    vbext_wt_FindReplace = 9,
    vbext_wt_Toolbox = 10,
    vbext_wt_LinkedWindowFrame = 11,
    vbext_wt_MainWindow = 12,
    vbext_wt_ToolWindow = 15
};

enum __declspec(uuid("be39f3dc-1b13-11d0-887f-00a0c90f2744"))
vbext_WindowState
{
    vbext_ws_Normal = 0,
    vbext_ws_Minimize = 1,
    vbext_ws_Maximize = 2
};

struct __declspec(uuid("0002e185-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
Windows;
    // [ default ] interface _Windows

struct __declspec(uuid("0002e187-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
LinkedWindows;
    // [ default ] interface _LinkedWindows

struct __declspec(uuid("0002e113-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
_VBProjectsEvents : IUnknown
{};

struct __declspec(uuid("0002e103-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
_dispVBProjectsEvents : IDispatch
{};

struct __declspec(uuid("0002e115-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
_VBComponentsEvents : IUnknown
{};

struct __declspec(uuid("0002e116-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
_dispVBComponentsEvents : IDispatch
{};

struct __declspec(uuid("0002e11a-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
_ReferencesEvents : IUnknown
{};

struct __declspec(uuid("0002e118-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
_dispReferencesEvents : IDispatch
{};

struct __declspec(uuid("0002e119-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
ReferencesEvents;
    // [ default ] interface _ReferencesEvents
    // [ default, source ] dispinterface _dispReferencesEvents

struct __declspec(uuid("0002e130-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
_CommandBarControlEvents : IUnknown
{};

struct __declspec(uuid("0002e131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
_dispCommandBarControlEvents : IDispatch
{};

struct __declspec(uuid("0002e132-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
CommandBarEvents;
    // [ default ] interface _CommandBarControlEvents
    // [ default, source ] dispinterface _dispCommandBarControlEvents

struct __declspec(uuid("0002e159-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
_ProjectTemplate : IDispatch
{
    //
    // Raw methods provided by interface
    //

      virtual HRESULT __stdcall get_Application (
        /*[out,retval]*/ struct Application * * lppaReturn ) = 0;
      virtual HRESULT __stdcall get_Parent (
        /*[out,retval]*/ struct Application * * lppaReturn ) = 0;
};

struct __declspec(uuid("32cdf9e0-1602-11ce-bfdc-08002b2b8cda"))
ProjectTemplate;
    // [ default ] interface _ProjectTemplate

enum __declspec(uuid("ffcf3247-debf-11d1-baff-00c04fb6c4a6"))
vbext_ProjectType
{
    vbext_pt_HostProject = 100,
    vbext_pt_StandAlone = 101
};

enum __declspec(uuid("0002e129-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
vbext_ProjectProtection
{
    vbext_pp_none = 0,
    vbext_pp_locked = 1
};

enum __declspec(uuid("be39f3d2-1b13-11d0-887f-00a0c90f2744"))
vbext_VBAMode
{
    vbext_vm_Run = 0,
    vbext_vm_Break = 1,
    vbext_vm_Design = 2
};

struct __declspec(uuid("0002e169-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
VBProject;
    // [ default ] interface _VBProject

struct __declspec(uuid("0002e167-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
Events : IDispatch
{
    //
    // Raw methods provided by interface
    //

      virtual HRESULT __stdcall get_ReferencesEvents (
        /*[in]*/ struct _VBProject * VBProject,
        /*[out,retval]*/ struct _ReferencesEvents * * prceNew ) = 0;
      virtual HRESULT __stdcall get_CommandBarEvents (
        /*[in]*/ IDispatch * CommandBarControl,
        /*[out,retval]*/ struct _CommandBarControlEvents * * prceNew ) = 0;
};

struct __declspec(uuid("0002e101-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
VBProjects;
    // [ default ] interface _VBProjects

enum __declspec(uuid("be39f3d5-1b13-11d0-887f-00a0c90f2744"))
vbext_ComponentType
{
    vbext_ct_StdModule = 1,
    vbext_ct_ClassModule = 2,
    vbext_ct_MSForm = 3,
    vbext_ct_ActiveXDesigner = 11,
    vbext_ct_Document = 100
};

struct __declspec(uuid("be39f3d6-1b13-11d0-887f-00a0c90f2744"))
Components;
    // [ default ] interface _Components

struct __declspec(uuid("be39f3d7-1b13-11d0-887f-00a0c90f2744"))
VBComponents;
    // [ default ] interface _VBComponents

struct __declspec(uuid("0002e163-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
_Component : IDispatch
{
    //
    // Raw methods provided by interface
    //

      virtual HRESULT __stdcall get_Application (
        /*[out,retval]*/ struct Application * * lppaReturn ) = 0;
      virtual HRESULT __stdcall get_Parent (
        /*[out,retval]*/ struct _Components * * lppcReturn ) = 0;
      virtual HRESULT __stdcall get_IsDirty (
        /*[out,retval]*/ VARIANT_BOOL * lpfReturn ) = 0;
      virtual HRESULT __stdcall put_IsDirty (
        /*[in]*/ VARIANT_BOOL lpfReturn ) = 0;
      virtual HRESULT __stdcall get_Name (
        /*[out,retval]*/ BSTR * pbstrReturn ) = 0;
      virtual HRESULT __stdcall put_Name (
        /*[in]*/ BSTR pbstrReturn ) = 0;
};

struct __declspec(uuid("be39f3d8-1b13-11d0-887f-00a0c90f2744"))
Component;
    // [ default ] interface _Component

struct __declspec(uuid("be39f3d4-1b13-11d0-887f-00a0c90f2744"))
SelectedComponents : IDispatch
{
    //
    // Raw methods provided by interface
    //

      virtual HRESULT __stdcall Item (
        /*[in]*/ int index,
        /*[out,retval]*/ struct _Component * * lppcReturn ) = 0;
      virtual HRESULT __stdcall get_Application (
        /*[out,retval]*/ struct Application * * lppaReturn ) = 0;
      virtual HRESULT __stdcall get_Parent (
        /*[out,retval]*/ struct _VBProject * * lppptReturn ) = 0;
      virtual HRESULT __stdcall get_Count (
        /*[out,retval]*/ long * lplReturn ) = 0;
      virtual HRESULT __stdcall _NewEnum (
        /*[out,retval]*/ IUnknown * * lppiuReturn ) = 0;
};

struct __declspec(uuid("be39f3da-1b13-11d0-887f-00a0c90f2744"))
VBComponent;
    // [ default ] interface _VBComponent

struct __declspec(uuid("0002e18b-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
Properties;
    // [ default ] interface _Properties

struct __declspec(uuid("da936b63-ac8b-11d1-b6e5-00a0c90f2744"))
Addins;
    // [ default ] interface _AddIns

enum vbext_ProcKind
{
    vbext_pk_Proc = 0,
    vbext_pk_Let = 1,
    vbext_pk_Set = 2,
    vbext_pk_Get = 3
};

struct __declspec(uuid("0002e170-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
CodeModule;
    // [ default ] interface _CodeModule

struct __declspec(uuid("0002e174-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
CodePanes;
    // [ default ] interface _CodePanes

enum vbext_CodePaneview
{
    vbext_cv_ProcedureView = 0,
    vbext_cv_FullModuleView = 1
};

struct __declspec(uuid("0002e178-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
CodePane;
    // [ default ] interface _CodePane

enum vbext_RefKind
{
    vbext_rk_TypeLib = 0,
    vbext_rk_Project = 1
};

struct __declspec(uuid("cdde3804-2064-11cf-867f-00aa005ff34a"))
_dispReferences_Events : IDispatch
{};

struct __declspec(uuid("0002e17c-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
References;
    // [ default ] interface _References
    // [ default, source ] dispinterface _dispReferences_Events

struct __declspec(uuid("0002e166-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"))
testVBE : Application
{
    //
    // Raw methods provided by interface
    //

      virtual HRESULT __stdcall get_VBProjects (
        /*[out,retval]*/ struct _VBProjects * * lppptReturn ) = 0;
      virtual HRESULT __stdcall get_CommandBars (
        /*[out,retval]*/ __missing_type__ * * ppcbs ) = 0;
```